# Check if data was already fetched, if not add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios, fetch

I would like to check if axios request already fetched certain data.

On first call i get 10 elements and store them in array. On second request i would like to check if existing data is in array, if yes do not add them again and if they are not in array add them.
It is written in Vuejs.

```
.then((response) => {
          this.receivedData = response.data
          
          for( let i = 0; i < this.receivedData.length; i++) {
              let receivedDataArray = [];
              receivedDataArray.push(this.receivedData[i].id);
              if(!receivedDataArray.includes(this.receivedData.id)) {
                receivedDataArray.push(this.receivedData);
                receivedDataArray = this.receivedData;
              }
            } 
        })
```

But i can not find an error. Please advise.

Comment: `this.receivedData = response.data` you issue is here. Everything you do later - is just iterating over what you have already overwritten. Write again your logic with comments, and I'm sure you'll be able to do it on your own.

Comment: Is this just a typo?  `this.receivedData[i].id` and `this.receivedData.id` are unlikely to both be valid.  Probably a bad idea to push both `this.receivedData[i].id` and `this.receivedData` into the same array.  And why push anything at all into that array if you're just going to orphan it with `receivedDataArray = this.receivedData`.  Many things are weird here.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the values you pushed into `receivedDataArray` on
`receivedDataArray = this.receivedData;`

Basicly, resetting it on every loop, so after the `for` ends, you have the `response.data` in `receivedDataArray`

Edit: Also you are not using the `[i]` index inside your `if`

Answer (score 1):

I have added comments to help follow my logic below. I believe all issues I can see with the code have been pointed out in other comments, so will just provide my solution to this answer.

It is untested, but hope that it helps.

```
.then((response) => {
         // If data has not already been added to receivedData, this is the first loop.
         if (!this.receivedData) {
              // So store the response
              this.receivedData = response.data;
              return;
         } else {
              for(const item of reponse.data) {
                   //  
                   if(!this.receivedData.includes(response.data[item])) {
                        // If not, push it to the array
                        this.receivedDataArray.push(response.data[item]);
                    }
               } 
          }
        })
```

Comment: Two things: the first `if` can be simplified to: `if (this.receivedData)` and if you don't need the index (here `i`) of the data just use the `for-of-loop` instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @F.Müller I have simplified the if statement as advised and switched from a for i loop to a for-of-loop, thanks.